# $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(a^x\right)=0,\:\:0<a<1$ proof

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I'm kind of a beginner in calculus so excuse me if my question is consider basic.

I have been wanted to prove that $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(a^x\right)=0,\:\:0<a<1$ by the limit definition and this is what I got:

Let $\epsilon > 0$.
we choose $M = max\{\frac{1}{log_a\epsilon},1\}\:$ and let $\:1<M<x\;,$ so we have that:

$|a^x -0| = a^x < a^\frac{1}{M} = \epsilon $

$=>\:\: |a^x -0| < \epsilon.$

But I'm afraid I might be using the definition incorrectly.

Would love to hear your thoughts :)

Comment: you must take $M>\log_a(\varepsilon )$.

Comment: but why? we are looking at 0<a<1 and for $a^x$ to be $< a^\frac{1}{M}$ we need to take M to be  $log_a\epsilon$

Comment: $a^x<\varepsilon \iff e^{x\ln(a)}<\varepsilon \iff x\ln(a)<\ln(\varepsilon )\iff x>\frac{\ln(\varepsilon )}{\ln(a)}=\log_a(\varepsilon ).$

Comment: You can use inequality $a^x\leq a^{\lfloor x\rfloor} =1/(1+b)^{\lfloor x\rfloor} \leq 1/(1+b\lfloor x\rfloor) $ where $b=(1/a) - 1>0$.